# PHP Timezone Name to Offset

Tags: php, timezone, offset

How would I go about converting a timezone name ("Asia/Dubai", "Europe/Andorra", etc) to a GMT offset in hours (or even seconds, since I can convert it from there).

Most people ask for the reverse, but I need to get a timezone offset from the timezone name provided by GeoNames.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but may solve your problem. Looks like you can query GeoNames directly for the offset, like this: http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2

Comment: Yeah, I am actually using GeoNames as a primary. The main problem is that they are currently overloaded, so I am trying to have a backup for when they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTC Offset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193499/utc-offset-in-php)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you can use the following

```
<?php

$timezone = 'Pacific/Nauru';
$time = new \DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$timezoneOffset = $time->format('P');
?>
```

Comment: have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to output in seconds

Comment: Works perfectly when changing "new dateTime" to "new DateTime" and "time()" to "'now'". Thanks!

Comment: Or just do `$time->getOffset()` to output in integer seconds

Answer (score 27):

Another option would be to use the available [`DateTimeZone::getOffset()`](http://php.net/datetimezone.getoffset) method, which returns the offset in seconds for the time zone at the specified date/time.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Andorra");
$offset   = $timezone->getOffset(new DateTime);
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it gives me the seconds. As opposed to `format('P')` which returns `hh:mm` format.

Answer (score 15):

I like using [PHP Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/):

```
$offset = Carbon::now('Europe/Andorra')->offsetHours;
```