# How do I get the format of "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ" in php?

Tags: php, date-format

I need to get a datetime format of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` to use in creating a hash to talk with a .NET server.  How can I get that format in PHP?  I don't know what "fffZ" even is to try to figure this out myself and can't find it online.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using PHP you can get it in this way:

```
date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.uZ')  //for the current time
```

You can find each character [at the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Although I'm not sure if the `Z` means the same in both languages.

Comment: Thanks, this outputs `2013-03-22EDT12:56:35.000000-1440016`.

Comment: I think its `date("Y-m-d\Th:i:s.v\Z")` for current time, the flag v is output the 3 integer before Z

Answer (score 4):

`.fffZ` refer to milliseconds and the timezone.

`.fff` specifies 3 decimal places of milliseconds.

`Z` is the timezone (+0000 UTC e.t.c).

You may find this page useful: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx)

Comment: I would add the link to PHP date documentation as he is asking to get it with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Steve You're totally right, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

> fff The milliseconds in a date and time value.Specifier.

and

> "z" Hours offset from UTC, with no leading zeros.

To get the corresponding format in PHP, see [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, fff is milliseconds:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Z is going to be timezone. You can handle getting that in PHP by http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php.

The rest should be pretty straight forward.

Edit: Actually, forgot that Z in .NET is going to be offset from UTC. Seems like you can get that from something similar to [UTC Offset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193499/utc-offset-in-php).