# PHP date() returning format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.uZ

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I have checked out the following question/responses: 
[How do I get the format of “yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ” in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574434/how-do-i-get-the-format-of-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-fffz-in-php)
The responses include links to Microsoft documentation to format dates but these do not work in PHP.

The the top answer suggest

`date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.uZ')  //for the current time`

This outputs
`2013-03-22EDT12:56:35.000000-1440016`

**Background**

I am working with an API which requires a timestamp in the format above.  The API is based in the UK (GMT) and my server is in Australia (AEST).

The example given in the API documentation ask for the date to be in this format:

`2011-07-15T16:10:45.555Z`

The closest I can get to this is date('c') which outputs:

`2014-07-03T16:41:59+10:00//Notice the Z is replaced with a time diff in hours`

I believe the 'Z' refers to a Zone but it is not mentioned in the PHP documentation.

Unfortunatly when I post this format, the API is reading the time and taking 10 hours off. I get an error saying that the date cannot be in the past (as it is checking against the local time in Melbourne, but seeing a time 10 hours earlier).

I have tried trimming the timestamp to remove the +1000 which the API accepts, but the record is showing as created as 10 hours earlier.

I need to match the timestamp required but I cannot find any way to replicate the above output, in PHP for Melbourne, Australia.  Any assistance is much appreciated.

*First question on SO so please let me know how I have gone*

Comment: Have you tried `date(DATE_ATOM);`?

Comment: Hi Alex - the output is the same as Date('c');  Tested just now and got ``2014-07-07T17:54:05+10:00``

Comment: If a solution is not posted, perhaps if you know the API will always trim 10 hours, a compromise would be to add an extra 10 hours to the time that you are sending? In effect, keeping track of two times, the 'real' time, and the one that satisfies the API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Z` stands for the timezone `UTC` and is defined in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which is your desired output format, extended by the millisecond part.

Before outputting the time, you'll need to transfer local times to UTC:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

then you can use the following format string:

```
echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH-i-s.\0\0\0\Z');
```

Note that I've zeroed the millisecond part and escaped the special characters `T` and `Z` in the format pattern.

Comment: Thanks; however again the output is ``2014-07-07T08:01:32+00:00``  - I am happy enough that the timezone is set to be correct for Australia/Melbourne.  It is more the output including the milliseconds, plus the Z character.  I am starting to think this is not a PHP function and that the API is requesting something that cannot be delivered

Comment: Yeah, I told you, this is valid ISO-8601. You are free to choose between `+00:00` or `Z`

Comment: Hmm, your question is hard to read. You just should have added the desired output format. Btw, if the API expects the `Z` this means it expects dates in **UTC**, not in Melbourne's timezone. Having this it should be easy get the expected output .. second ...

Comment: Sorry - I thought the desired format was clear in the title.  I will put it front and center in future posts.  I believe what is causing my issue is not PHP, but the API.  They are validating against Australia/Melbourne timezone, but expecting GMT.  When I send GMT it is rejected as being 10 hours in the past.  When I send Australia/Melbourne, it is accepted and stored as 10 hours in the future.

Comment: Have you used `setTimeZone()` as I've suggested?

Comment: Yes.  I carried out exactly the steps in your post, sent the using the UTC timezone and it was rejected as 10 hours old. I sent with Australia/Melbourne timezone, and it was accepted but posted as 4am on the 8th of July.  It is an issue with the API provider.

Comment: The following worked to generate an acceptable format for the API.  1. ``$dt new DateTime()``.  2. ``$dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601)``. This outputs ``2014-07-08T09:18:01+1000`` - notice the missing colon in the hour-offset from UTC.  ``date('c')`` includes the colon.  This is not the answer to my original question, but it does fix my problem.

Comment: date('c') was exactly what I needed to get the timezone to show "+00:00" as I required.

Comment: @Patrick Can you please give an example of how you used `data('c')` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The 3 number last before `Z` is just the 3 decimal place of time in milliseconds

The function `microtime(true)` gave the current time in milliseconds, would output like `1631882476.298437`
In this situation it would be **.298Z**

##### Examples

- 1652030212.6311 = .631Z
- 1652030348.0262 = .026Z
- 1652030378.5458 = .545Z

##### Codes

```
$milliseconds = microtime(true);
    
// Round to integer 
$timestamp = floor($milliseconds);

// Get number after dots
$uuuu = preg_replace("/\d+\./", "", "$milliseconds");

// Get last 3 number decimal place
$u = substr($uuuu, 0, 3);

// Print date by the timestamp timestamp
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $timestamp). ".{$u}Z";
```