# Google calendar API daylight savings time issues (time zones)

Tags: php, timezone, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate Google calendar into one of my apps.

I have been following a useful tutorial but have been getting stuck with telling Google the correct time.

When I add an appointment I use this time stamp format.

Date        Time        Timezone
2013-04-02T18:00:00.000+00:00

Now this seems to work apart from I can see its adding an hour for current daylight savings. How do I over come this or use PHP to generate the correct date format for me.

Any help or links for guide I can read will be great, all I can find is about people having problems with reoccurring datetimes.

This is my json code for adding and appointment,

```
$date = '2013-04-02';
        $starttime = '18:00';
        $endtime = '20:00';

{
         "start": {
          "dateTime": "{$date}T{$starttime}:00.000+00:00"
         },
         "end": {
          "dateTime": "{$date}T{$endtime}:00.000+00:00"
         },
         "summary": "$title",
         "description": "$title"
        }
```

Comment: If you use your _actual_ timezone in the timestamp value you pass, it should work fine automatically.

Comment: Is the extra hour being added before you send the call off to the API or does it show up after you send a call with a timestamp an hour less than what it records? Also, any code/php datetime settings you can provide will be helpful.

Comment: I have added the json code i am using.

Comment: I too have this problem. I am in the GMT timezone and if I create an event for 15:00 using the API it gets created as 16:00. The date being sent is `2013-09-12T15:00:00+00:00`. Also tried using `date_default_timezone_set("GMT")` just in case. Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The `+00:00` part of the timestamp is the GMT offset of your timezone, here, it's set to "plus zero" or in human, "my time zone is GMT." If you are one hour off of GMT, you need to change this part to either `+01:00` or  `-01:00` depending whether your an hour ahead or behind the GMT time, respectively. You could also get the [UTC Offset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193499/utc-offset-in-php) if you please.

Alternatively, you can convert everything to GMT date/time, but that's a lot more work and with the timezone support built-in, it's easier to use that.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone will find my solution useful. I was having problems when inserting events using Google Calendar API around the time we switch to/from GMT.

I was using DateTime and its constant RFC3339. The RFC3339 format includes time offset (like +01:00). This is probably causing a problem in Google Calendar API because Calendar absolutely ignores the value in timeZone attribute once you specify the dateTime attribute.

Only solution for me was to stop using the RFC3339 format with time offset. Now I use the following (RFC3339 like) DateTime format: `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` (note the missing P attribute on the end, RFC3339: `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`).

Then you have to specify the timeZone attribute. For example 'Europe/Prague'.

Finally my code looks like this:

```
$atts['summary'] = $this->title;
$atts['location'] = $this->location;
$atts['description'] = $this->description;
$atts['start']['dateTime'] = $this->start->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
$atts['start']['timeZone'] = $this->timeZone; //"Europe/Prague"
$atts['end']['dateTime'] = $this->end->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
$atts['end']['timeZone'] = $this->timeZone; //"Europe/Prague"
```